# Missing Function in Filemaker

Tags: csv, filemaker

I'm troubleshooting a Filemaker script made by someone else before me. I'm trying to determine what this missing function would be in the code below. The purpose of my script is to import data from a csv, which is done with `Import Records`, but I still think I need to fix the lines below for the whole script to work. It seems like the function is taking a csv file from our server and putting in on the local machine.

If anyone could give me an educated guess as to what the `<Function Missing>` is, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
<Function Missing>( "//192.168.168.81/htdocs/API/Pipedrive/Deals.csv";
"C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker/Server/Data/Documents/Deals.csv")
```

Comment: Could the function come from a third-party plugin? There are some at [filemaker-plugins.com/features/file-manipulation/](http://filemaker-plugins.com/features/file-manipulation/) which have file copy functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It ended up being `CopyFile` from `360Works WebAssistant Plugin`, the line of the script looks like `CopyFile( "//192.168.168.81/htdocs/API/Pipedrive/Deals.csv";
"C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker/Server/Data/Documents/Deals.csv")` and that copy's the file from the internet location to local storage.

Comment: You may want to explain how you used `CopyFile` so that future visitors can benefit from your solution.